# rewrite to WWW and https from every combination

Tags: windows, https, isapi-rewrite

i use isapi rewirte from helicon.

i have this code for non-www to www rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} (on)?
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^(?!www\.)(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)
RewriteRule .? http(?%1s)://www.%2%3 [R=301]
```

works fine for the non-www to www part... 
than i need it the www if it is on http to be redirected to https

```
RewriteCond  %HTTPS (?!on).*
RewriteCond Host: (.*)
RewriteRule (.*) https\://$1$2 [I,RP, L]
```

what do i need to change in this so it will work?

i get https://folder/index.asp
the entire domain is gone

**i have tried samething else but it is not working as well, here it is:**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^(?!www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)
RewriteRule .? https://(?%1www.)%2 [R=301]
```

if i try domain.com i got https://www.
and if i tried www.domain.com i got https://www.

what it means i solved half of my problem! but why the rest of the url is not there?!

Answer (score -1):

My answer considers answer for ISAPI_Rewirte version 3.
You get https://folder/index.asp because your host value is inside the %1, not the $1.

I'd suggest:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond Host: www\.(.*)
RewriteCond {REQUEST_URI} (.*)
RewriteRule .* https\://www.%1%2 [NC,R=301,L]
```